# Neo4j cypher query to delete child and grandchild nodes of a a specific node

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I’m looking for a cypher query to include in python module where I’m trying to delete a the nodes and sub nodes along with relationships of them if one specific node property matches.
For example, if Node match I found is
match (n) where n.name = ‘parent’
Then I want to delete all the nodes/relationships connected to that specific node along with sub-nodes and their relationships of those nodes I am trying to delete .

Sample Data : https://photos.app.goo.gl/5PPnNSLVRKvJzm6a8

So, basically I am looking for the query which will delete all the nodes(N1 to N8) after parents node (PN1) and associated relationships. So PN1 and rest of other nodes having incoming relationships will stay.

Comment: I think I found an answer here : https://ios.developreference.com/article/20802033/Neo4j+query+to+delete+all+nodes+and+relations+directly+or+indirectly+connected

MATCH (root { value: '32'})-[r1*]->(x)
OPTIONAL MATCH ()-[r2]->(root)
FOREACH(r IN r1 | DELETE r)
DELETE r2, root, x;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like that:

MATCH (n)--(p)--(gp) WHERE n.name = 'parent' DETACH DELETE p, gp

Comment: Thank you Alexander. 
But This query deleted all the relationships in the database and didn't delete nodes I wanted to delete. I have added link of the topology in original question.